# PCF - cf push - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcf

We are trying to perform an EAR deployment in PCF, the deployment bundle's size is around 200 MB. The buildpack we use is WAS Liberty buildpack. While we do a `cf push` we are consistently getting this below error,

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
X-Cf-Routererror: endpoint_failure (context deadline exceeded)
io: read/write on closed pipe
```

Is there a specific reason for this behavior apart from network bandwidth, latency etc.,?

Comment: `endpoint_failure` means your app did not handle the request presented to it. See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/troubleshooting-router-error-responses.html#app-errors. Does your application start successfully? Do you see any requests that succeed? Like can you make simple requests for static assets? What do you see in `cf logs`? What is the output of pushing your app & what is your `cf push` command and manifest.yml (if using).

Comment: The app does not get started at all, `cf push` fails during the package upload itself with the above error. No app level logs could be seen.

Comment: OK, please include the entire output from `cf push` including the command you're running in your question above. The context you've provided isn't enough to understand the problem.